# Using ADB to enable File transfer mtp, USB debugging enabled, device set to charging

Tags: debugging, usb, adb, mtp

I have a tablet I am using for automated testing. It is set to usb debugging. If the pc reboots or cable is disconnected/reconnected the unit defaults to `usb configuration = charging`, but usb debugging is always enabled.  `adb` does not detect the device.  I have to manually set usb from charging to mtp file transfer for it to be detected by adb.  The goal is to programmatically change the device from charging to mtp file transfer if connected or the pc reboots.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Most devices have in their developer settings menu an option to set the default USB mode. It it exists you can just change it there, making your question unnecessary.

Comment: It defaults to charging if it reboots or disconnects from pc.

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to enable MTP over ADB with the command

```
adb shell svc usb setFunctions mtp
```

Comment: the tablet responds with device not found.  adb root responds with the same command.  If I manually change the usb to mtp initially windows recognizes the device.